# CASE using prisma

Tags: prisma

```
SELECT * from posts
   ORDER BY LEAST(
      CASE WHEN ISNULL(replyto) THEN id ELSe replyto END, id
   );
```

How to convert this to prisma or do I have to use raw query here?
I wanted to use pagination with `take`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10335) to support CASE statements with Prisma. Using a Prisma [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) would be an option in this case.